# Multiple REGEXP values not working in SQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a dynamic query for my site. The query is done using this:

```
$sql='SELECT CONCAT(issues.type,"0",issues.kbid) as KBID,issue_tasks.PARENTID as Parent,issues.issuesummary as Summary,products.productdescription as Product,organizations.shortname as Organization,issue_priorities.description as Priority,date_format(issues.createddate, "%d/%m/%Y") as Reported,date_format(issues.lastupdated, "%d/%m/%Y") as Updated,issue_status.statusdescription as Status,issue_resolutions.resdescription as Resolution,users.logon as Assigned FROM issues
        INNER JOIN issue_priorities ON issue_priorities.VALUE = issues.PRIORITY - 1 
        INNER JOIN issue_resolutions ON issue_resolutions.RESID = issues.RESOLUTION 
        INNER JOIN users ON users.ID = issues.ASSIGNEDUSERID
        INNER JOIN products ON products.PRODUCTID = issues.PRODUCTID
        INNER JOIN organizations ON organizations.orgid = issues.creatingorg
        INNER JOIN issue_status ON issue_status.STATUSID = issues.STATUS
        LEFT JOIN issue_tasks ON issue_tasks.CHILDID = issues.KBID
        WHERE ';

if(isset($_SESSION['summ']))
{
$sql.= sprintf('issues.issuesummary REGEXP "%s"', implode('|', $words));
}
```

**EDIT :** My full SQL query:

```
SELECT CONCAT(issues.type,"0",issues.kbid) as KBID,issue_tasks.PARENTID as Parent,issues.issuesummary as Summary,products.productdescription as Product,organizations.shortname as Organization,issue_priorities.description as Priority,date_format(issues.createddate, "%d/%m/%Y") as Reported,date_format(issues.lastupdated, "%d/%m/%Y") as Updated,issue_status.statusdescription as Status,issue_resolutions.resdescription as Resolution,users.logon as Assigned FROM issues INNER JOIN issue_priorities ON issue_priorities.VALUE = issues.PRIORITY - 1 INNER JOIN issue_resolutions ON issue_resolutions.RESID = issues.RESOLUTION INNER JOIN users ON users.ID = issues.ASSIGNEDUSERID INNER JOIN products ON products.PRODUCTID = issues.PRODUCTID INNER JOIN organizations ON organizations.orgid = issues.creatingorg INNER JOIN issue_status ON issue_status.STATUSID = issues.STATUS LEFT JOIN issue_tasks ON issue_tasks.CHILDID = issues.KBID WHERE issues.issuesummary REGEXP "sabre|rtf"
```

But I keep getting an error like so:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1139 Got error 'empty (sub)expression' from regexpSQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1139 Got error 'empty (sub)expression' from regexpCould not execute query!!!

I am not sure why I get an encapsulation error in this.

Comment: It looks like `$yesh` is empty, can you verify that the regular expression is what it's supposed to be?

Comment: So what is the final value of `$sql`?

Comment: This code is messed up. Try to use proper names for your variables and fix the indentation. If possible, design your schema in a way so you wouldn't need to use such regexp in a query.

Comment: the final WHERE clause of sql would be like "WHERE issues.issuesummary REGEXP 'abc|xyz' "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `$words` contains the words you want to use in your regular expression, you can simplify the code:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['summ']) && count($words)) {
    $sql .= sprintf('issues.issuesummary REGEXP "%s"', implode('|', $words);
}
```

Comment: i still get the same error. my $words contains something like this : $words[0]=abc and $words[1]=xyz

Comment: Could you update your original code to include the complete generated SQL statement, please?

Comment: Well, the SQL statement itself looks okay - which MySQL Version are you using? Perhaps it is a bug in the engine? (Getting desperate here :) )

Comment: i tried the same query on my phpmyadmin. it worked but not in site :/

Comment: @HelloMan: I am intrigued that you have accepted this answer when you say that it did not solve your problem.  For the benefit of future readers, could you elaborate on what the problem was and how this answer helped you?

Comment: I used jqgrid plugin for the site. It required a dynamic query and jqgrid accepted parameters of WHERE clause as '?' only. I had to create a pattern of '?,?' how much ever parameters i needed to pass and pass it to jqgrid.

Answer (score 1):

The error that you have encountered, [`ER_REGEXP_ERROR`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_regexp_error), is an error generated by the MySQL server when the regular expression pattern that you have provided cannot be parsed.  In other words, your regular expression is syntactically incorrect.

The message given in your particular case, "*empty (sub)expression*", suggests that the regular expression contains a subexpression that is empty.  Without seeing the final regular expression that your code generates, it's impossible to say for sure—but since you combine a number of subexpressions with the `|` alternation operator, it would be a reasonable guess that one or more of those subexpressions is empty: this would happen if at least one of the elements of your `$words` array is ([converted to](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.casting)) the empty string `''`.

All this said, it's not at all clear why you are using regular expressions here at all.  If `$words` contains regular expression patterns, then it may be a reasonable approach—although in that case one really ought to place each subexpression in brackets when joining them (in order to avoid any operators that have lower precedence than alternation messing with your intention).  On the other hand, if `$words` just contains literal values that you wish to match exactly, MySQL's [`IN()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) operator would be more efficient, appropriate and correct:

```sql
WHERE issues.issuesummary IN ('abc', 'xyz', ...)
```

This could be achieved with the following PHP code:

```php
$sql .= "issues.issuesummary IN ('".implode("','", $words)."')";
```

However, note that the elements of `$words` must first be *escaped* in order to avoid bugs with certain characters (that would also give rise to SQL injection vulnerabilities)!  Better yet, you could parameterise each literal.

How to do either of these things will depend on which [MySQL API](https://php.net/manual/en/mysql.php) you're using—since you have not indicated any in your question, I think specific examples are beyond the scope of this answer.

Comment: according to your answer, it queries the issuesummary column for data with "abc" and "xyz" but i want to query data which contain the word "abc" or "xyz" not exactly matching the data.

Comment: @HelloMan: Then you should consider building a `FULLTEXT` index and using `MATCH ... AGAINST(...)`.

Comment: any example on how to do that?